# Different history depending on where git log is called

Tags: git

I'm attempting to view the history of a directory in my git repo. I'm seeing 2 different histories depending on the directory from where I call git log.

**Case 1 (from root of repo):**

```
$ git log path/to/files
```

Returns one commit

**Case 2 (from sub directory):**

```
$ cd path/to/files
$ git log .
```

Returns 13 commits, with the last commit displayed (earliest commit) is the same as Case 1.

Shouldn't the two cases return the same history?

I've also tried "--" and "--follow" in Case 1 to no effect.

Comment: What version of Git are you running?

Comment: What platform are you on?  (Is your file system case insensitive?)

Comment: I'm using git version 1.8.1.rc2.6.g18499ba

on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: As far as I understand it, yes, the two cases should return the same history---and do when I try this locally using Git 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

They are different. The `git log .` lists the log, but `git log path/to/files` restricts the log output to changes pertinent to those files:

```
[\--] <path>…
```

Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be. See History Simplification below for details and other simplification modes.

Paths may need to be prefixed with ‘`-- '’ to separate them from options or the revision range, when confusion arises.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log